# how to decode a object filed in a form using thymeleaf and spring

Tags: spring, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I post a form to a controller using thymeleaf. A field of the form is an object named person. In controller, I print this String, it looks like a map that contains all the fields in the person.
Now, I just need the id of person, so I can get the person object. I try to change the parameter to Person, but it says cannot convert the String to the person. The only way I know is to use the regex. But I think it is a little stupid. Is there any easy way to solve it?

Here is the **HTML**

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal center-block"
      style="width: 40%" th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${project}" method="post">

    <select th:field="*{person}">
        <option th:each="person:${persons}" th:value="${person}" th:text="${person.name}">
            Wireframe
        </option>
    </select>

</form>
```

At first, I had a controller like this

```
@PostMapping("/index")
public String save(String projectName, Person person, String description, 
                   @RequestParam(name="subject")String subject, String date) {
    System.out.println(person);               
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

But I had an error saying cannot convert string to person.

Then I changed the **controller** like this

```
@PostMapping("/index")
public String save(String projectName, String person, String description, 
                   @RequestParam(name="subject")String subject, String date) {
    System.out.println(person);               
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

In console, I got this `Person(id=1, name=mike, age=44, sex=女)`. If I want to get this object, I need to use regex to split the String, then I will get the Id.
Is there a way to get the person object easily?

Comment: Please post your errors and make your requirements clear.

Comment: There is no error, and I update the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it, change the html like below:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal center-block" method="post"
      style="width: 40%" th:action="@{/index}" th:object="${project}">
  <select th:field="*{person}">

    <option th:each="person:${persons}" th:value="${person.id}"
            th:text="${person.name}">Wireframe</option>
  </select>
</form>
```